# OnMouseDown creates "Screen position out of view frustum" error in Visual Studio

Tags: hololens

How to reproduce:

- Make a new empty hololens project with a cube in the middle.
- Deploy it on the hololens and check that it works.
  I use "Debug/x86/Remote Machine" as configuration.
- Create a new script and add an empty method called OnMouseDown()

> ```
> void OnMouseDown()
>     {
>
>     }
> ```

- Don't attach the script to anything!
- Deploy again on the holo lens.
- The following error pops up in Visual Studio after the app is already runnig on the hololens. Afterwards the app is immediatly closed.

> Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 0.000000, 0.000000)
>   (Camera rect 0 0 1268 720)
>
> (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Camera/Camera.cpp Line:
>   2626)
>
> The program '[4740] onmousedowntest.exe' has exited with code
>   -2147483645 (0x80000003).

My setup:

- Windows 10 Pro 1703 (Build 15063.483)
- Visual Studio 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Unity 5.6.2f1

Am I the only one who gets this error in such a simple program?

I do get a warning from unity:

> Game scripts or other custom code contains OnMouse_ event handlers.
>   Presence of such handlers might impact performance on handheld
>   devices. UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Can anyone explain to me why a script that is not used, with a method that is empty, can create such an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot OnMouseDown() (or other mouse events) anywhere in your compiled code base for a Hololens project. Even if the script isn't active in the scene being deployed.

I discovered this on a cross platform Hololens/ARKit project. In my case I wrapped the the OnMouseDown in a #if UNITY_IOS preprocessor directive.